# Apache hashbang url problems

Tags: apache2

I set up an older Rails 2 project on a brand new Apache@Debian#squeeze. The project itself could be a single pager, using links to scroll page up and down. My links look like that:

```
http://mydomain.com/en/#home
```

These links do fine as long as JavaScript intercepts the click event and simply scrolls to the intended section. In case the user leaves the single page and opens one where these links (still the same) cannot be followed via JavaScript, I only receive an:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /en/ on this server.
```

If I change the link to:

```
http://mydomain.com/en#home
```

everything works fine and as expected. But I do not want to change my link structure. It already worked well at an older Debian5 box.

I expect that to be an Apache2 configuration issue, but do not find anything useful in the net.

Looking forward to any kind of enlightenment.
Thx 
Felix

Comment: The problem is not the fragment but the path `/en/`. The fragment isn’t even transmitted to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how or where you are working with javascript related to this problem, but let me tell you this.

Everything after the hashtag `#` is ***never*** passed to the server. Its HTTP standardization, it is just not passed to the server.

It is only intended to navigate to anchor within the webpage, and today used for a lot of new techniques including, but not limited to, xss scripting, javascript hooks, etc

It is possible that links are prohibited to load with an onclick event and some javascript does something instead, but it is not possible that you end up on this page `http://mydomain.com/en/#home` if `http://mydomain.com/en/` does not work.

However to solve your problem you probably have to adjust your your apache rewriting rule (or enable mod_rewrite at all?) to also capture links with trailing slashes.

The link `http://mydomain.com/en/` `http://mydomain.com/en` is something different and ***could*** serve a completely different page.

I would ***strongly*** recommend not to get a mess here and do a strict permanent redirect from one to the other. Which you choose for primary usage is up to you.

I prefer a trailing slash and can also supply arguments for that, but they can be invalidated easily and replaced by some to suggest the opposite. You should find plenty on discussion on that if you search for trailing slash here.

To *solve*  your problem please try to find the according `RewriteRule`, copy it and add it one more time with a trailing slash. See whether it works and make a redirect to the url without trailign slash.

You may also edit your answer and post your server config to get help with that.